# Is It possible to change the property from hover to click during a specific break point using media queries in React?

Tags: reactjs

Right now my li tag has a mouseenter and mouseleave effect, but when I shrink my site down to mobile view, I want it to change to onClick instead.

So the code below shows my menu with the dropdown. Whenever I click on the hamburger menu in mobile view, it will trigger the active class on the `<ul>` and open up the mobile view. Then when I hover over the li tag it will display the dropdown menu.

Instead of it displaying when I hover, I need it to display when I click the ul tag only at the breakpoint of 960px.

```
    <ul className={click ? 'nav-menu active' : 'nav-menu'}>
      <li
        className='nav-item'
        onMouseEnter={onMouseEnter}
        onMouseLeave={onMouseLeave}
      >
        <Link to='/' className='nav-links' onClick={() => setClick(false)}>
          Home <i class='fas fa-caret-down' />
        </Link>
        {dropdown && <Dropdown />}
      </li>
      <li className='nav-item'>
        <Link
          to='/services'
          className='nav-links'
          onClick={() => setClick(false)}
        >
          Services
        </Link>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Is that something that is posssible to do? Or would I have to completely redo my code?

Answer (score 0):

It most definitely is. And there are many options of how you could do it, these are some that come to my mind at first:

**Option #1:**

You could render 2 completely different things based on media query, something like this:

```
<div className="hidden-xs">
  <ol onClick={() => {}}></ol>
</div>

<div className="hidden-lg">
  <ol onMouseLeave={() => {}} onMouseEnter={() => {}}></ol>
</div>
```

**Option #2:**

You could disable certain functions based on current viewport

```
const onMouseEnter = () => {
   if (window.width > something) {
     return;
   }

   do something otherwise
}

const onClick = () => {
   if (window.width < something) {
     return;
   }

   do something otherwise
}
```

I would recommend taking a look at some of these articles & modules:

[Medium post about media queries in React](https://medium.com/better-programming/how-to-use-media-queries-programmatically-in-react-4d6562c3bc97)

[react-media](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-media)

[react-responsive](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-responsive)

Comment: is it window.width or window.innerWidth? Also, if I just put 768 is that referring to px? because what I put right now isn't working properly for me

Comment: @Brian I've added some helpful link in my answer, I hope this can guide you in the right direction and helps you, Google is also your friend, now that you know what to search for!

Comment: So window.innerWidth worked for me, but now my issue is whenever I click on home it redirects to the home path, which cancels out the dropdown onclick function. Do you know a good ux way to fix this?